# Store an extra property in a matplotlib.collections

Tags: matplotlib

Segments are in red
Ticks in blue.

How to save extra information, for example the segment number, on the added ticks that I have added from a mouse event on the segment ?

I would be able to identify from which segment a tick comes from.

[image]

The complete running example is available from :
https://github.com/PBrockmann/StripesCounter/blob/main/lineCollection_02.py

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to add reproducible example code to your post.  The easiest solution is to use a `label` when calling `plot`.   Most matplotlib objects also allow to be extended with new attributes, just write `segment[i].my_data = ....` to create the extra data.

Comment: Not sure to follow you. Yes matplotlib objects also allow to be extended with new attributes but do understand how to do that on item of a collection.
`from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection ; 
segmentsCollection = LineCollection([ [[2,5],[6,8]], [[1,2],[6,4]], [[2,2],[8,2]] ], linestyle='solid', color='r') ;
segmentsCollection[1]`

You get: `TypeError: 'LineCollection' object is not subscriptable`

So how to save extra data on item of a collection remains unclear.

Comment: I was assuming you would be creating the lines one by one.  Did you note my first phrase?  It is very important to have a **reproducible example** to provide a good answer. Otherwise, stackoverflow would just be an awkward guessing game.  Would you mind to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71817856/edit) your post?

Comment: Done from my gitHub project.
Thank you for your interest. 
In fact diffent questions come from the use of a LineCollection.
1) How to store extra_data for a specific Line ?
2) How to highlight a line when you pass over with the mouse ? I have coded this feature but I would have like to modify the color of a line from the LineCollection.